# selenium python check hide error

Tags: python, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

So, i need to create some test for check login/registration.
I trying to catch hide error when user enter email incorrect.
Steps:
1. Enter not valid email.
2. Press button "Login".
3. Should show error what "password or email is not correct".

Below i wrote 2 function. 
How i can combine this two function? 
Second function always show me "OK" status.

```
  def test_login_user(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("https://courses.edx.org/login")
    driver.find_element_by_name('email').send_keys("email24")
    driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys('12345678')
    driver.find_element_by_name('signin').click()

 def test_error(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get('https://courses.edx.org/login')
    error = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.status.submission-error')
    if error.is_displayed():
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, instead of locating elements by `name` - switch to `id` and `class` attributes - there are multiple elements with the same name.

Also, you need to use [Explicit Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits) to wait for elements to become visible.

Working example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://courses.edx.org/login")
email = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "login-email")))
email.send_keys("illegal")
driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys('12345678')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.login-button').click()

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.status.submission-error")))
    print True  # in your case inside a function it would be "return True"
except TimeoutException:
    print False  # in your case inside a function it would be "return False"
```